# PHP with ODBC to remote db, where does driver need to be and can I drop SSL on the connection?

Tags: php, ssl, odbc, navision

I need to connect from a web LAMP (PHP) environment to a remote Navision installation which has ODBC drivers on the server.

Does the web server need the ODBC drivers on it locally as well? Or does PHP connect to the Navision server environment with it's own local drivers?

Also, can I drop SSL on this connection for security - if so which component is it dropped onto? The ODBC connection?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, the Navision is on an office server, connected to the web and is the only part of this system at present that has the ODBC drivers.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you connect to Navision. Does Navision provide some kind of API by which you can access it  (Webservices or something)? In that case, the LAMP server can use that API.

If you need to access the database behind Navision, then PHP needs access to the database. Either over ODBC or directly if possible (like FreeTDS if the database in question is a MS-SQL Server)

Comment: Thanks for your help :)Yes, we'd access it via PHP and ODBC. But does this mean we'd need ODBC drivers on the LAMP environment?

Comment: I'll need to access the db directly in NAV from the web server, so we'd use the odbc query functions to query direct in PHP. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: in that case you'd indeed need ODBC drivers on your Linux server. I never had good experiences with ODBC under Linux though, so accessing the database directly (FreeTDS, OCI, whatever the database is) will for sure work better.